# Jquery if statement does not apply to all elements inside brackets

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this code for my nav menu and when I'm in smartphone view (i.e the class "responsive" is added) I don't want all the stuff starting line 3 to happen. However my background still changes color when I scroll down. It feels like my browser somehow confuses the closing bracket of my first if statement with some other one. What did I do wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!$(".site-nav").hasClass("responsive")){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".site-nav").css("top",Math.max(-10,130-$(this).scrollTop()));
    });

    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wn = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(wn > 130){
        $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(225,225,225,0.7)");
    }
    else{
        $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }

    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if statements inside events instead

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).on("scroll",function(){
          if(!$(".site-nav").hasClass("responsive"))
          {

            $(".sitenav").css("top",Math.max(-10,130-$(this).scrollTop()));
            var wn = $(window).scrollTop();

            if(wn > 130){
                $(".sitenav").css("background","rgba(225,225,225,0.7)");
            }
            else{
                $(".site-nav").css("background","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
            }
          }


        });

    });
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll()` and `$(window).on("scroll"` do exactly same thing...no need for duplication

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for information :) I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Might need to open up another question but in my CSS I want the background-color of .site-nav to be blue when .responsive which does not work in the case my screen was larger before. Any ideas why?